# Nodemailer returns 404 when using POST form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a contact me form using Nodemailer. Whenever I post with my form it always returns a 404 error and I suspect there is an error in my Async/Await code. My code outputs the first console.log then returns 404. I am quite new and simply cannot find my error, there is very little documentation on using async and await with Nodemailer, making it that much more difficult. I have tried replacing my code with their test code on github and it works fine.

**mailer Controller | exports to Mailer Routes**

```
module.exports = {
    send: async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
        console.log(`Preparing Email`);
            const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                service: `gmail`,
                auth: {
                    user:`psuedoEmail@gmail.com`,
                    pass:`password`
                }
            });
            console.log(`reading mail options...`);
            const mailOptions = {
                from: req.body.from,
                to: `psuedoEmail@gmail.com`,
                subject: req.body.subject,
                text: req.body.text
            };
            console.log(`Attempting to send Mail`);
            const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, response) =>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    res.redirect(`/contact`);
                } else {
                    console.log(`Info: `, info, response);
                    transporter.close();
                    res.redirect(`/`);
                }
            });
        } catch (error){
            next();
        }
    }
};
```

**UPDATE WITH ROUTES AND FORM**

**Form**

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="from">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="text">Text:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**routes**

```
const express = require(`express`);
const router = express.Router();
const Mailer = require(`../controllers/mailer`);

router.route(`/contact`)
    .post(Mailer.send);

module.exports = router;
```

**Error As Requested by Commentor**

```
GET /contact 304 7.008 ms - -
{ Error: Something Happened!
    at app.use (home/project/app.js:29:17)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] /node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix 
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at 
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params /node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next 
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at 
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next 
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle 
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router 
/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12) status: 404 }
POST / 404 0.200 ms - 43
```

Comment: Please remove `const info = await` and change it to only `transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, response) =>{` and try.

Comment: same error but it breaks before the first console.log now

Comment: Please post the error you are getting.

Comment: you are using **response** as parameter in callback but using **res** keyword for refrencing

Comment: Still nothing, plus it's a second callback and should be different no?

Answer (score 0):

have you changed your auth to your credentials (your email and password) ? if yes then kindly allow non secure apps to access gmail from gmail settings or else it won't allow access to your gmail account

Comment: everything is set correctly, the password and email are dummy for placing on here